# create database in hive with multiple locations having sentry enable

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-sentry

I am creating a database in hive with multiple location for example

CREATE DATABASE sample1 location 'hdfs://nameservice1:8020/db/dev/abc','hdfs://nameservice1:8020/db/dev/def','hdfs://nameservice1:8020/db/dev/ghi'

but i am getting error while doing this. Can anyone help in this kind of creating a database with multiple locations is allowed ? Is there any alternate solution for this.

PS: My cluster is sentry enabled

Answer (score 0):

Which error? If that is

> User xx does not have privileges for CREATETABLE

then look at 
http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-SQL-Apache-Hive/quot-User-does-not-have-privileges-for-CREATETABLE-quot-Error/td-p/21044

You may have to omit LOCATION, and upload file directly to a hive warehouse location of that hive schema. I can't think of a better workaround.